# Splice multiple arrays in multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an multidimensional array

```
[{id:0, type:1}, {id:1, type:1}, {id:2, type:2}]
```

What I aim to do is to remove all type 1 and so the desired result should leave `id:2, type:2`

```
tmpType = 1;
for (var i in arr) {
    if(arr[i].type == tmpType) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

However in the loop, from what I understand it will loop thrice but everytime I splice, the loop differs. This is the result I am getting.

```
{{id:1, type:1}, {id:2, type:2}}
```

If i have 3 kinds of type:1, I will always have the last one still in the array.

Comment: Your first literal is invalid syntax

Comment: I think you meant to do `[{id:0, type:1}, {id:1, type:1}, {id:2, type:2}]` instead of `{{id:0, type:1}, {id:1, type:1}, {id:2, type:2}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `splice` changes the *length* you either need to move your iterator or iterate downwards.

You should also be using `for`, not `for..in` to iterate over an *Array*

```
var arr = [{id:0, type:1}, {id:1, type:1}, {id:2, type:2}];

var type = 1,
    i;                                  // OR    // i = arr.length;
for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {          // while (i-- > 0) {
    if (arr[i].type == type) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

arr; // [{"id": 2, "type": 2}]
```

Other answers suggest using a the *filter* method of *Arrays* which is a great alternative option and you may find it cleaner. However, please be aware the result of these two ways are slightly different as this way will modify the original *Array* reference (*"has side effects"*), whereas the *filter* method will create an entirely new instance of *Array* and leave the original untouched.

---

You can think of *filter* like this, which also shows why it's a bit expensive

```
function filter(arr, test) {
    var i,
        arr_out = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        if (i in arr && test(arr[i]) // invoking test each time is expensive
            arr_out.push(arr[i]);
    return arr_out;
}
```

`splice` can be expensive too, however, as you are moving all the indicies around.

The least expensive way to do this without *side effects* (i.e. original left alone) is to do a mix of the two; a manual `for` loop which `push`es to a new *Array* with out test written into it, not invoked seperately

```
// arr as before
var arr2 = [],
    i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i].type === type) // doing our test directly, much cheaper
        arr2.push(arr[i]);
arr2; // desired array
```

For a original modified, easiest option is to use the `splice` method I wrote at the start of this answer.
The other option is to copy the original, `var arr2 = arr.slice()`, then empty the original, `arr.length = 0;`, then do the last loop I showed except with `arr` and `arr2` swapped around to re-populate `arr`

Comment: this is what i want but couldn't write it out. didn't know about the filter method, is there efficiency difference between yours and filter? I would need the original to be touched so would be going for this method. thanks heaps.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with arrays with 10,000+ items, you will *never, ever, ever, ever* notice a performance difference.

Comment: @jmar777 please see the spec, http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.20 part 9.b. . It is true that the efficiency optimisation will not be noticeable unless you're doing some really heavy work though

Comment: @PaulS. I would confess to being a massive arse, but I'm too busy eating crow at the moment. Thanks for the correction...

Comment: @PaulS. Also, even if I had been right, my (removed) reply was just childish. Please accept my apology. :\

Answer (score 3):

You should probably just use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this:

```
var arr = [{id:0, type:1}, {id:1, type:1}, {id:2, type:2}];

var filtered = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.type !== 1;
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/tafuhasoti/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an actual array.

```
var data = [{id:0, type:1}, {id:1, type:1}, {id:2, type:2}]
//Array has a method filter
var filterdata = data.filter(function(element, index, array){
  return element.type == 2;
})
//filterdata will contain an array of only objects that have type 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should loop backwards through the array. Using splice looping forwards will mean that you'll skip past the element after the one you splice on each iteration, now that it has the same index as the one you removed.

```
var arr = [{id: 0, type: 1}, {id: 1, type: 1}, {id: 2, type: 2}];
for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
        if (arr[i].type === 1) arr.splice(i, 1);
}
```

You could also do this:

```
var arr = [{id: 0, type: 1}, {id: 1, type: 1}, {id: 2, type: 2}];
arr = arr.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.type !== 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really meant:

```
[{id:0, type:1}, {id:1, type:1}, {id:2, type:2}]
```

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var oldArr = [{id:0, type:1}, {id:1, type:1}, {id:2, type:2}];
var newArr = oldArr.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.type !== 1; 
});
```